# Write non english characters using a RandomAccessFile in java

Tags: java, character-encoding, randomaccessfile

I am trying to write some text to a file using a RandomAccessFile object but the non-english characters are not saved correctly.

Specifically, this sentence --> "und NotenstEnder Libero"

is saved like this --> "und Notenst•nder Libero"

where 'E' character is not english (the ascii code is 917 i think).

The code i am using is this:

```
file = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
...
file.seek(file.length());
file.writeBytes("The data i want");
```

How can i avoid this and write the correct text?

(PS: I know about file.writeChars, and i am wondering if there is another way!)

Comment: writeBytes(String s):  Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits, so it's like using ASCII encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem might be your file encoding. You should use the correct encoding (probably UTF-8) , e.g.:

```
byte[] b = "The data i want".getBytes("UTF-8");
file.write(b);
```

Note that if you're using a text viewer/editor to check the file, depending on which one you're using you might have to write a UTF-8 byte order mark at the beginning of the file or tell the viewer/editor to use UTF-8 if it can't figure it out by itself.

Comment: i can use writeBytes with a single string as an attribute but i cannot use it with (byte[], int, int). Is there i library i should install?

Comment: @MaRiOs oops, sorry that's a typo. It`s `write(byte[], int, int)` or even `write(byte[])` which delegates to the internal method `writeBytes(byte[], int, int)` passing 0 and b.length.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I suppose now i should change the way i am reading the file? Because i write the text i want but when i read it i still have problems with the non-latin characters. (i am reading with file.readline() )

Comment: @MaRiOs yes, if you know the file's encoding you should use that when reading the file. In general it's advisable to use a defined endcoding rather than to rely on the system encoding (which many IO methods do, but fortunately they often have counterparts which allow you to specify the encoding).

Answer (score 1):

You mean the Greek letter Ε (GREEK CAPITAL LETTER EPSILON) instead of the Latin letter E (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E)?

In addition to `writeChars()`, which would work, there is a [`writeUTF8()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) method that will work as well. Instead of writing two bytes per character, it will use a variable number of bytes, depending on the character code.

Files store bytes. Text is a sequence of characters; in Java, a `char` is two bytes. You have to specify one of many, many methods of translating between characters and bytes. Some methods like UTF-8 handle any character, while many others only handle a specific subset of characters, like Latin or Cyrillic. You have to pick a character encoding and then keep track of what you used so that you can decode the file later.

Answer (score 0):

You want your Java code to be UTF-8. If you encode the characters using unicode \unnnn, you can have any unicode characters.

Here's how you would encode your example:

```
String spanish = "\u00E1\u00E9\u00ED\u00F3\u00FA";
System.out.println(spanish); // prints áéíóú
```